# Having trouble concatenating strings from lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

When I run the following code:

```py
size = 5

alph = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
lis_t = [n for n in alph]
lis = lis_t[(26-size):]

for i in range(2*size):
    if i<size:
        print("".join([n+'-' for n in lis[:i]] + lis[i] + ['-'+n for n in lis[:i]]).center(size, '-'))
    if i > size:
        print("".join([n+'-' for n in lis[:(9-i)]] + lis[i] + ['-'+n for n in lis[9-i]]).center(size, '-'))
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I don't know what's wrong with my print statements.
It should do something like this:

```
--------e-------
------e-d-e------
----e-d-c-d-e----
--e-d-c-b-c-d-e--
e-d-c-b-a-b-c-d-e
--e-d-c-b-c-d-e--
----e-d-c-d-e----
------e-d-e------
--------e--------
```

Comment: Some of the items in your `join()` expression are plain strings, and some are lists.  You can't do that.

Comment: It looks to me like lis[i] is a string, and you are trying to use ‘+’ to concatenate it to a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this variation:

```
size = 5
alph = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'

for n in list(range(size))+list(range(size-1))[::-1]:
    print('-'.join('-'*(size-n-1)+alph[-size:-size+n]+alph[-size+n:-size-1:-1]+'-'*(size-n-1)))
```

Output:

```
--------e--------
------e-d-e------
----e-d-c-d-e----
--e-d-c-b-c-d-e--
e-d-c-b-a-b-c-d-e
--e-d-c-b-c-d-e--
----e-d-c-d-e----
------e-d-e------
--------e--------
```

---

---

You can also:

```
size = 5
alph = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'

for n in list(range(size))+list(range(size-1))[::-1]:
    a,b = alph[n-size:-size-1:-1], '-'*(size-n-1)
    print('-'.join(b+a[1:][::-1]+a+b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with this expression:

```
 [n + '-' for n in lis[:i]] + lis[i] + ['-'+ n for n in lis[:i]]
```

First, for `size = 5`, the length of `lis` is 5 elements.  But, its index `i` is ranging from `0` to `9` (`range(2*size)`), so nearly half the values of `i` will cause an index error on `lis`.

Second, assuming `i` is in bounds, we're conatenating three objects:

```
[n + '-' for n in lis[:i]]  # a list
lis[i]  # a string
['-'+ n for n in lis[:i]]  # a list
```

To make this work we would need express it as all lists:

```
[n + '-' for n in lis[:i]] + lis[i:i+1] + ['-'+ n for n in lis[:i]]
```

I'll leave you to sort out the rest.  For me, this seems a potentially *recursive* problem:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

def alphagram(size, row=1):
    if row:
        start = size - abs(row)

        letters = alphabet[size-1:start:-1] + alphabet[start:size]

        print('-'.join(letters).center(4*size-3, '-'))

        alphagram(size, row+1 if row != size else 1-row)

alphagram(6)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
----------f----------
--------f-e-f--------
------f-e-d-e-f------
----f-e-d-c-d-e-f----
--f-e-d-c-b-c-d-e-f--
f-e-d-c-b-a-b-c-d-e-f
--f-e-d-c-b-c-d-e-f--
----f-e-d-c-d-e-f----
------f-e-d-e-f------
--------f-e-f--------
----------f----------
>
```

We can do a compact *iterative* solution in the manner of @AnnZen but translate it into Python ;-)

```
from itertools import chain
from string import ascii_lowercase as lower

size = 5

for n in chain(range(1, size+1), range(size-1, 0, -1)):
    print('-'.join(lower[size-1:size-n:-1] + lower[size-n:size]).center(4*size-3, '-'))
```